# Parse TXT-File-Information to Integer

Tags: java, android, file, parsing, counter

I could not find anything related (even if there are hundrets of Parse-Questions):

Similar to a good old website counter, I like to store a number in a txt-file on the sd-card. Each time a method gets activated in the application, it should read a number of a txt-file, add 1 and save it again.

If I try the code below, it creates a strange String, no Int. How to solve this problem? :-(

```
FileWriter writer;
File file;
FileInputStream fileIS;  

public void implementCounter()
{
    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    int counter = 0;

    try{

           File f = new File(sdcard +"/Experiment/Counter.txt");             
           fileIS = new FileInputStream(f);          
           BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIS));                               
           //counter = Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
           String readString = new String();             

           //just reading each line and pass it on the debugger          
           /*while((readString = buf.readLine())!= null){            
              Log.d("line: ", readString);           
           }*/
           readString = buf.readLine();
           try {
                counter = Integer.parseInt(readString.toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
               Log.d("line: ", "XXX: " + readString + "E");
            } 


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {          
           e.printStackTrace();          
        } catch (IOException e){             
           e.printStackTrace();          
        }


    //Create / Write LogFile
    file = new File(sdcard + "/Experiment/Counter.txt");

    try 
    {
        counter++;
        writer = new FileWriter(file ,false);
        writer.write(counter);         
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The idea is, that the new FileWriter simply overwrites the old file with one number higher.

Comment: why do you want to save it in a file? Are you okay with just saving it in such a way that it will persist even when the app is updated?!

Answer (score 0):

These two functions are static. You can use them to retrieve your count and to save it (set it). For more info, try to get acquainted with [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You are welcome (:

```
    private static boolean setMyLovelyCount(Context mContext, int value) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                "mylovelyprefs", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("mylovelyCount", value);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    private static int getMyLovelyCount(Context mContext, int defaultvalue) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(
                "mylovelyprefs", 0);
        return prefs.getInt("mylovelyCount", defaultvalue);
    }
```

Comment: Haha, I was nearly there :-)
Thank youu!!